# Power BI Embedded

Tags: powerbi-embedded

1. We embedded a report into web application and now a user want to build his
   own dashboard from the report but pin a tile to dashboard option is
   not available can we embed pin to dashboard option? Can we handle it
   in API?
2. As we have email subscription (scheduled) for reports in `power bi`
   service, how will we handle the same in our embedded application
   side, if the user want to see the updated reports on daily basis which
   should be scheduled automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Power BI Embedded (PBIE) is PaaS, so you have to write you own code to handle some cases using official and legal SDK. PBIE doesn't work the same way as Power BI Services (PBIS). 
As for you questions:

1. You can't do the same thing with pinning visuals into dashboard. It supported only inside PBIS.
2. You can't do this neither.

PBIE is more like engine, some core things that draw specific report into you app. There are no any features like report sharing or subscription. This is by design. Those features were implemented as part of PBIS and doesn't fit PBIE. You should implement something similar on your app level. 
Play with PBIE and explore SDK [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html).